# Group-concat problems, the result is wrong

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have this query that works correctly (tested on phpmyadmin):

```
SELECT articoli.id AS id_articoli,
              articoli.titolo,
              articoli.descrizione,
              galleria.id AS id_galleria,
              group_concat(galleria.foto) as immagini
              FROM articoli
              LEFT JOIN galleria
              ON articoli.id = galleria.rif_id
              WHERE articoli.genere1 = 1       
              AND articoli.visibile = 1
              GROUP BY articoli.id
              ORDER BY articoli.id ASC
```

With this mysql query I am able to fetch all item that belong to a category and for every item i can fetch all the respective images.

Now I am trying to update/upgrade this query and trying to fetch also the videos (if any) for the item (this for every item that belong to a category).

I was able to upgrade the query as below but it gives me a strange result and obviously I am doing the query in the wrong way.. but I don't know what I am doing wrong..

```
SELECT articoli.id AS id_articoli,
              articoli.titolo,
              articoli.descrizione,
              galleria.id AS id_galleria,
              group_concat(galleria.foto) as immagini,
              group_concat(videos.video) as video
              FROM articoli
              LEFT JOIN galleria
              ON articoli.id = galleria.rif_id
              LEFT JOIN videos
              ON articoli.id = videos.rif_id  
              WHERE articoli.genere1 = 1       
              AND articoli.visibile = 1                  
              GROUP BY articoli.id
              ORDER BY articoli.id ASC
```

This query returns me (if some video exists)the same number of video and images... If the item has 3 images it returns also 3 videos and that's not true because some item could have 3 images and 1 video or viceversa.. Can you help me to fix the query?

Comment: Just change your `group_concat` to `group_concat(distinct`...

Comment: Thanks, it works, honestly, before posting my question i looked for an answer but i wasn't able to find it.. thanks again, Davide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT a.id AS id_articoli,
       a.titolo,
       a.descrizione,
       group_concat(distinct g.foto) as immagini,
       group_concat(distinct v.video) as video
FROM articoli a LEFT JOIN
     galleria g
     ON a.id = g.rif_id LEFT JOIN
     videos v
     ON a.id = v.rif_id  
WHERE a.genere1 = 1 AND     
      a.visibile = 1                  
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.id ASC;
```

Notes:

- I added table aliases.  This makes the query easier to write and to read.
- The `distinct` keyword should remove the duplicates in the two lists.
- I removed `g.id AS id_galleria`.  This is not appropriate, because there are multiple matches.  You can use an aggregation function on `g.id` (such as `MIN()`, `MAX()`, or `GROUP_CONCAT()`).
- The `GROUP BY a.id` is fine, assuming the `id` is the primary key (or unique) in the table and the only unaggregated columns come from that table.

Also, the `DISTINCT` works if you have a handful of images and galleries.  If you have larger amounts of data, you might need another strategy, such as aggregating before joining.

Comment: your solution also work, thanks to you too. Davide